# Discard elements in a matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

I would like to know how discard elements in a matrix in Matlab.
I have a Matrix 'A' that contains all possible combination with 8 persons and for each persons I have three possible choice, for example :

```
 A=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2;
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3;
    1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1;
    1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2;
    1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3;
    1 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 ;
    ....
                   ];
```

etc.. for all elements.

Now I have a new vector B=[2 2] that contains the values for the first two persons, and I would like to obtain a new matrix from A with all possible combination like above, discarding all combinations that not contains the values of B for the first two persons.

I hope to be clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, the last column is for the first person and the second person has the second last column?

Comment: I read it as: line 1, all persons choose option 1. line 2: only person 8 chooses option 2, rest chooses 1. line 3: person 8 chooses 3, the rest chooses 1. Is that how it should be interpreted?

Comment: exactly @WouterKuijsters . Now I would like to erase all elements that not cointains  specific values for two persons.

Comment: So, something like this - `A(~ismember(A(:,1:2),[2 2],'rows'),:)`?

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you also posted the expected output...

Comment: So the columns are the number of people and the rows are...?

Comment: Exactly as @Divakar , but the element without [ 2 2] will be erased, so the contrary of A(~ismember(A(:,1:2),[2 2],'rows'),:)

Comment: Then just remove the tilde: `A(ismember(A(:,1:2),[2 2],'rows'),:) `

Comment: If you have just 2 elements in B, then the fastest way would be with `A(A(:,1) == B(1) & A(:,2) == B(2),:)`.

Comment: A better option would be not to create the entire matrix in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sizeA = size(A,1);        % check how long array A is

index = 1;
for ii=1:sizeA
    if ~(A(index,1) == B(1,1)) || ~(A(index,2) == B(1,2))     % if either entry doesn't match
    A(index,:) = [];                                          % clear the line
    else
    index=index+1;                                            % else: move to next line
    end
end
```

Note that it is by no means an elegant solution as it is not easily adapted: the `ismember` function Divakar suggested in the comments suits that purpose better:

```
A(ismember(A(:,1:2),[2 2],'rows'),:)
```

What this does, is that it checks row-wise if the first two entries are equal to `[2 2]`, and only returns those rows. For clarification, this is equivalent to:

```
indices = ismember(A(:,1:2),[2 2],'rows')
A(indices,:)
```

Where `indices` is a column vector containing a 1 at each row where the first two entries match `[2 2]`, and a 0 otherwise.

Comment: Feel free to add that ismember solution in it.

Comment: ismember  is the solution. Thanks a lot